# vimeo upload private videos from django

Tags: django, vimeo

I managed to upload videos to vimeo from my django app, but the privacy settings doesn't work so far, what I tried is as follow, any help is appreciated.
first try

```
v_upload = v.upload(path,  data={'name': name, 'description': description,
                                                 'privacy.embed': 'whitelist', 'privacy.view': 'disable'})
```

second try

```
                rs = requests.session()
                api = 'https://api.vimeo.com'
                url = api + v_upload
                headers = {"Authorization": 'bearer ' + token}
                rs.patch(url, data={'privacy.embed': 'whitelist', 'privacy.view': 'disable'}, headers=headers)
```

as per the above setting the video should be private, but it appears as public, how I can make it to private?

Comment: your question is not cleared, what privacy setting is doesn't work

Comment: as per the above setting the video should be private, but it appears as public

Comment: you should probably check their API documentation better in case you are missing something.